# new min.js files repeatedly created

Tags: javascript, php, visual-studio, min.js

I have a file "script.js" and now new "min.js" are repeatedly made such as **script.min.min.js** then **script.min.min.js** then **script.min.min.min.js**.

I'm guessing it has to do with how I en-queued my script in "functions.php" but don't know enough about this

deleting all files but original

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array(), '20190731', true );
```

```
gulp.task('lint', () => 
  gulp.src(['./js/*.js'])
  .pipe(prettyError())
  .pipe(eslint())
  .pipe(eslint.format())
  .pipe(eslint.failAfterError())); 

gulp.task( 'scripts', gulp.series('lint', () => 
  gulp.src('./js/*.js')
  .pipe(terser())
  .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.js' }) 
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'))));
```

I just want script.js and maybe script.min.js if necessary

Comment: What are you using to minify your files? Can you include your configuration here?

Comment: gulp.task('lint', function() {
  return gulp
    .src(['./js/*.js'])
    .pipe(prettyError())
    .pipe(eslint())
    .pipe(eslint.format())
    .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
});
   
     gulp.task(
  'scripts',
  gulp.series('lint', function() {
    return gulp
      .src('./js/*.js')
      .pipe(terser())
      .pipe(
        rename({
          extname: '.min.js'
        })
      )
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));
  })
);

Comment: It is very hard to read code in comments. You should edit your question directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are minifying your scripts and placing them in the same directory that they came from. So, the next time the minification runs, the minified scripts are re-minified and an extra `.min` is added to the file name

Typically, you want to move the scripts to a distribution folder of some sort. It might look like this:

```
gulp.task( 'scripts', gulp.series('lint', () => 
  gulp.src('./js/*.js')
  .pipe(terser())
  .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.js' }) 
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))));
```

Also, be sure to excluse the `dist` folder from version control (usually `.gitignore`).